# Calculating the probability of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I'm absolutely baffled by this question:

> Given X~Geo(0.75), Y|X = x~Geo(1/(x+1)
>   What is P(E(Y|X) = 2) ?

I'm very obviously missing something - I know how to calculate a conditional expectation, but the probability of one? I have no idea.
Would love guidelines and tips on how to begin solving this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Note that $\E[Y\mid X]$ **is a random variable** (it is a function of $X$). To find $\E[Y\mid X]$, first find $\E[Y\mid X = x]$ for any constant $x$, then replace $x$ with $X$ in the expression you find. As a hypothetical example, if you were to find that $\E[Y\mid X]=\color{blue}{x^2}$ for all $x$, then you could conclude that $\E[Y\mid X]=\color{blue}{X^2}$.

Comment: $E(Y\mid X)=g(X)$ (say) is a random variable. If you can find out what $g$ is, then there should not be a problem since the distribution of $X$ is given.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Solved it!

Comment: Then maybe post an answer here?