# probability of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Is there a general formula for this type of questions?

Given data:
$$X \sim \mathrm{Geo}(0.09)$$
$$Y|X=x \sim \mathrm{Geo}(1/x+1)$$

How do I calculate $\mathbb P(\mathbb E(Y|X)=3)$?

Comment: *Which* of the two geometric distributions does your book use? What is the probability mass function, and support?

Comment: did you mean p(1-p) ^n-1?

Comment: Yes.   That would have a support of $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and expected value of $1/p$.

Comment: Also asked somstime back: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229903/321264.

Answer (score 0):

First determine what is $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$.   (Well, it is a function of $X$, but what function is it?)

Let $g(x)=\mathbb E(Y\mid X=x)$. Evaluate $\mathbb P(g(X)=3)$

Comment: yes, I've tried to find g(x), but it's a sigma that runs on values of Y, so I didn't know how to find it

Comment: What is the expected value for a Geometric distributed random variable with a success rate of $(1/x+1)$? @nof

Comment: (1/x+1)(x/x+1)^y-1

Comment: No.  The *expected value*.

Comment: solved it. thank you!